# pandoc error: Permission denied

Tags: permissions, manjaro, troubleshooting, pandoc

I'm on Manjaro Linux. I have `texlive-most` installed.

I'm trying to make pdf files from md with pandoc. However, I keep getting `Permission denied` errors. I've tried using `pdflatex` and `pdfroff`.

---

Run with the default `--pdf-engine=pdflatex`:

```
$ pandoc test.md -o test.pdf
warning: kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories: /usr/bin:/usr/bin/share/texmf-local/web2c:/usr/bin/share/texmf-dist/web2c:/usr/bin/share/texmf/web2c:/usr/bin/texmf-local/web2c:/usr/bin/texmf-dist/web2c:/usr/bin/texmf/web2c:/usr:/usr/share/texmf-local/web2c:/usr/share/texmf-dist/web2c:/usr/share/texmf/web2c:/usr/texmf-local/web2c:/usr/texmf-dist/web2c:/usr/texmf/web2c://texmf-local/web2c:/://share/texmf-local/web2c://share/texmf-dist/web2c://share/texmf/web2c://texmf-local/web2c://texmf-dist/web2c://texmf/web2c.

kpathsea: Running mktexfmt pdflatex.fmt
mktexfmt: Permission denied
warning: kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories: /usr/bin:/usr/bin/share/texmf-local/web2c:/usr/bin/share/texmf-dist/web2c:/usr/bin/share/texmf/web2c:/usr/bin/texmf-local/web2c:/usr/bin/texmf-dist/web2c:/usr/bin/texmf/web2c:/usr:/usr/share/texmf-local/web2c:/usr/share/texmf-dist/web2c:/usr/share/texmf/web2c:/usr/texmf-local/web2c:/usr/texmf-dist/web2c:/usr/texmf/web2c://texmf-local/web2c:/://share/texmf-local/web2c://share/texmf-dist/web2c://share/texmf/web2c://texmf-local/web2c://texmf-dist/web2c://texmf/web2c.

kpathsea: Running mktexfmt pdflatex.fmt
mktexfmt: Permission denied
Error producing PDF.
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
I can't find the format file `pdflatex.fmt'!
```

Quick investigation:

```
$ ll /usr/bin/mktexfmt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Nov  1  2019 /usr/bin/mktexfmt -> fmtutil

$ ll /usr/bin/fmtutil
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 48 Nov  1  2019 /usr/bin/fmtutil -> /usr/share/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/fmtutil.pl

$ ll /usr/share/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/fmtutil.pl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 49K Nov  1  2019 /usr/share/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/fmtutil.pl

$ locate pdflatex.fmt
/var/lib/texmf/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt

$ ll /var/lib/texmf/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7.7M Jun  5 09:27 /var/lib/texmf/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt
```

---

Run with `--pdf-engine=pdfroff`:

```
$ pandoc --pdf-engine=pdfroff test.md -o test.pdf
pandoc: pdfroff: createProcess: runInteractiveProcess: exec: permission denied (Permission denied)
```

---

Running `pandoc` with `sudo` works but I'd rather not have to use `sudo` to generate pdfs. I see that `mktexfmt` has `execute` permission and `pdflatex.fmt` has `read` permission for everyone. I'd also like to use the default `pdflatex` instead of another engine.

How should I fix this `Permission denied` problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the problem. I had run `sudo firecfg` after installing pandoc which caused `pandoc` to be symlinked and sand-boxed by firejail. The problem was fixed by doing `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/pandoc` which removes firejail's symlink of pandoc, effectively removing pandoc from sand-boxing.